# Visual Studio 2012 Project: Page cannot be displayed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis, localhost

I have a project which I moved from one computer to the other. The project worked fine on the initial computer but had to get rid of that computer so copied the project folder to the new computer. Now, on runing the project in the new computer, I get a page that give different messages in deferent browsers:

- IE: Page cannot be displayed
- Chrome: This webpage is not available
- Firefox: Firefox failed to establish a connection whith the server at
  localhost.

I run the project using ctrl + F5.
The project is set to use the Local IIS web server (with virtual directory localhost/projectname) and is configured for adfs authentication.

I tried running the project straight from IIS but the same outcome.
I tried creating a blank project a running it on the new machine and all worked well.

How could I fix this please?

Comment: How are you running the project?  We're going to need more information than just a description of each browser's generic error page.

Comment: Ctrl + F5. Sorry, this is so strange I am unsure of what info might be needed to figure this out. I run the project using VS run tool. Ctrl+F5 and also in debug mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page in question required HTTPS and not HTTP; but I wass missing the IIS binding for HTTPS. I followed the instructions [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/722979/Setting-up-IIS-with-HTTPS-Binding) to create a certificate and binding HTTPS using that certficate; and that solved the issue.